# Get all the open ports for a remote host in linux

Tags: networking, telnet, hosts, port

Trying to connect to a particular port for a remote host. The host is reachable (checked via ping command) but the port is not accessible.

Is there any way to check all accessible ports for that remote host from my server.

Note: The server is secured server for an enterprise,nmap or any third party tool is not available and installable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried with Below script worked fine

```
for i in host1 host2; 
do 
timeout 10 ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' $i -A "exit"
if [[ $? == 0 ]]
then 
echo "host $i is sshable"
ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' $i -A <<'EOF'
k=`hostname`
netstat -altnp| awk '$0 ~ /LISTEN|ESTABLISHED/'| awk '{print $4}'| awk -F ":" '{print $NF}'| awk '{if(!seen[$1]++)print $0}'| sed "1i below are open ports on the host '$k'"
EOF
else echo "host $i is not sshable"
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This script worked for single port scan

```
if timeout 5 bash -c '</dev/tcp/kernel.org/443 &>/dev/null'
then
  echo "Port is open"
else
  echo "Port is closed"
fi
```

I'm not sure if 1 second is too fast to catch an open port but here is the full range of ports.

```
#!/bin/bash
for PORT in {1..65535}; do
timeout 1 bash -c "</dev/tcp/45.62.xxx.xxx/$PORT &>/dev/null" &&  echo "Port $PORT is open"
done
```